# Differences between PE and Nylon

Tags: irrigation

So I want to assemble a misting irrigation system for trees and have to choose between PE tubing or Nylon tubing.

PE has 5.5mm wall thickness, nylon has 4mm wall thickness. Both are rated for 80-100 bar of pressure.

Which should I go with? Are there any advantages/disadvantages between them? I suspect nylon is more UV-resistant, can handle freezing temperatures better?

Comment: 80-100 bar (1160-1450 PSI) seems rather high....black PE is very sunlight resistant. I don't think nylon is particularly sunlight resistant, and I'm not sure that non-black PE is either, but black PE well pipe is often left exposed to sunlight without issue.

Comment: Max pressure is not an issue because I will not be exceeding 10 bar. I know it's not exactly misting at 10 bar, but for me its good enough. The reason I want to switch to this system instead of the classic dripping system is because fittings are metal and easy to handle, they seem more reliable. The plastic ones keep breaking